# Get missing file name in a sequence of files

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

In a folder i have many files, they are sequential, type ABC001.csv,ABC002.csv,ABC003.csv and so on. Sometimes this sequence breaks, then there are missing files and I need to identify which of the sequence are missing in the folder manually, we have more than 700files.
Does anyone here know a power shell script to help me with this task?

Comment: Is the `ABC` prefix part of the sequence number or just a sample prefix? In other words, does `ABC999` roll over to `ABD000`  or `ABC1000`?

Comment: One route would be Get-Childitem, pull out ints, compare vs array from 1 to largest int. What errors are coming up in your code at the moment?

Comment: do you really need powershell v3? that is so far out of date that i wonder ...

Answer (score 1):

If all files to be counted always have a naming format `ABC<3-digit number>.csv`, then you could do this:

```
# get an array of integer sequence numbers from the files
$sequence = (Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter 'ABC*.csv' -File).BaseName | 
             Where-Object { $_ -match '(\d{3})$' } | ForEach-Object { [int]$matches[1] } | 
             Sort-Object -Unique

# get the missing numbers (if any) and output filenames to be collected in $missingFiles
$missingFiles = Compare-Object $sequence (1..($sequence[-1])) -PassThru | ForEach-Object {
    'ABC{0:D3}.csv' -f $_  # reconstruct the filename with the missing number
}

# output on screen
if (@($missingFiles).Count) {
    Write-Host "Files missing:" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $missingFiles
}
else {
    Write-Host "All files are in sequence" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Of course, change the rootpath of the files (here 'D:\Test') to your own

Answer (score 0):

In this example,

1. The script is located in the same location as a folder named "Temp".
2. The "Temp" folder had files ABC001.csv through ABC717.csv.
3. Files ABC123.csv and ABC555.csv were deleted from "Temp" folder.

```
for ($i = 1; $i -lt 718; $i++) {
    $FileName = $PSScriptRoot + '\Temp\ABC{0:d3}.csv' -f $i
    if(-not (Test-Path -Path $FileName -PathType Leaf)) {
        Write-Host "Missing $FileName"
    }
}
```

Output when ran:

```
Missing 123
Missing 555
```

Comment: I replaced Temp with my folder path, but the output i am getting with full folder path and missing file. Am i missing something here?
Missing \Temp\ABC001.csv 
Missing \Temp\ABC002.csv 
Missing \Temp\ABC003.csv
Missing \Temp\ABC004.csv
Missing \Temp\ABC005.csv
Missing \Temp\ABC006.csv

Comment: @StarHunt, is the script and folder at the same location?  Lets say the script is located at C:\Programming\ps1\FindMissingFiles\FindMissingFiles.ps1, then $PSScriptRoot will be "C:\Programming\ps1\FindMissingFiles".  And `$PSScriptRoot + '\Temp\ABC{0:d3}.csv'` will become "C:\Programming\ps1\FindMissingFiles\Temp\ABC{0:d3}.csv".  But lets say the script and the files are in unrelated locations, say the files are in the "C:\Temp" folder, then replace `$PSScriptRoot + '\Temp\ABC{0:d3}.csv'` with `'C:\Temp\ABC{0:d3}.csv'`.